# Using intersect with 2 large sets to get the distinct count - MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a calculated member which represents an active customer. That would be the following;

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Active Customers] AS
  Count ( nonempty( Filter (
    ( [Customer].[Customer Key].Members, [Measures].[Turnover] ),
    [Measures].[Turnover] > 0
  ) )  )
```

This works great, when I want to get active customers in the current period and previous ones, as I get my time dimension, and use the CurrentMember, CurrentMember.PrevMember and CurrentMember with the Lag function in order to get customers who were active in previous periods.

My problem is when I want to get the count of customers, who are common in different members. Say I want to get customers who are active in the current period, and NOT in the previous period. Or another case, active in current, and active in previous. Because of this, I would need to use the **INTERSECT** function, and my customer dimension has 4 million records. This is already a subset of 9 million records.

So when checking for a customer who is active in 2 consecutive periods, I do this (The Active Previous Period, and Active Current Period is basically the calculated member above, however with **CurrentMember** and **CurrentMember.PrevMember**) :

```
set [Previous Active Customers Set] AS
   Filter (
    ( [Customer].[Customer Key].Members, [Measures].[Active Previous Period] ),
    [Measures].[Active Previous Period] > 0
   ) 

set [Current Active Customers Set] AS
   Filter (
    ( [Customer].[Customer Key].Members, [Measures].[Active Current Period] ),
    [Measures].[Active Current Period] > 0
   )  

member [Measures].[Active 2 consecutive periods] as 
count(INTERSECT([Current Active Customers Set],[Previous Active Customers Set]) )
```

This takes forever. **Is there anyway to improve, or go around this performance problem of using the INTERSECT with large sets? Or maybe optimizations on the MDX query?** I tried always using a subset of my customers dimension, but this only reduced the number of records to less than 4 million - so it's still large. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume you can speed this up if you avoid using named sets and calculated members as far as possible.

One step towards this would be as follows: Create a new fact table with foreign keys just to your customer and time dimension, and add a record to it if a customer was active on that day. Build a measure group, let's say "activeCustomers" based on this table, just using "count" as the measure. But make this invisible, as we do not need it.

Then, you can replace

```
count( nonempty( Filter (
( [Customer].[Customer Key].Members, [Measures].[Turnover] ),
[Measures].[Turnover] > 0
) ) )
```

with

```
count( Exists(
[Customer].[Customer Key].Members,
<state your time selection here>,
"activeCustomers"
) )
```

`Exists` should be more efficient than `Filter`.

Another optimization approach could be the observation that instead of intersecting two sets generated via Filter, you could define one set with a more complex filter, avoiding that AS is looping along the customers twice, and then intersecting the results:

```
set [Active Customers Set] AS
   Filter (
    ( [Customer].[Customer Key].Members, [Measures].[Active Previous Period] ),
    [Measures].[Active Previous Period] > 0
    AND
    [Measures].[Active Current Period] > 0
   )
```

Comment: Hi @FrankPI - I was trying to avoid creating any new tables, or maybe measure groups based on views, and to go the MDX/calculated sets/members way only. My named sets above are already a subset of the actual set - and still I am getting poor performance. So there is nothing that can be improved coding wise above?

Comment: I added another idea to the end of my answer that does not require changing the table structure.

Comment: Would the filter 2nd parameter [Measures].[Active Previous Period] limit the condition in any way?

Comment: @Mez I do not understand your question. But `Intersect(Filter(S, cond1), Filter(S, cond2))` is logically equivalent to `Filter(S, cond1 AND cond2)`.

Comment: Hi @FrankPI, I created a view based on customers which are all time active (have to have at least one record in the activity fact), and this limited my customer set a lot. So now, I got MDX queries running very fast when I want to see customers active in the current period, previous period etc. However, still slow when getting those which are active in 2 periods. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: @Mez I would assume using `([Customer].[Customer Key].Members * {[Customer].[Active Flag].&[yes]})` in the above queries wherever `[Customer].[Customer Key].Members` is used so far should make them faster.

Comment: I created a new dimension which contains active customers only - and that sped up the process quite a bit. I have another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26267916/mdx-active-in-current-period-and-not-active-in-previous-period, which is related to active and inactive periods of a customer which is more specific to my prior question.